# Почему Yii2 создает на сервере кучу сессий с __flash|a:0:{}?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

На сервере сталкиваюсь с периодическим переполнением временной папки. Нашел в папке **tmp** кучу файлов **sess_** с содержимым вида **__flash|a:0:{}**
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Конфиг Yii2 очень помог бы.

Comment: flashmessages используете?

Comment: Да. Использую. Но непонятно то ли проблема в том что слишком много сессий эти флеш сообщения порождают, то ли в том, что эти сессии не чистятся сами

Comment: Они стираются, после того как отобразятся